# Is recursive query an option for concatenating text for building a path

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest, lateral-join

Simplifying a bit. I have the following data structure:

```
| id       | name           | traversal_ids[] |
| -------- | -------------- |-----------------|
| 1        | container1     | {1}             |
| 2        | container2     | {2}             |
| 3        | subcontainer1  | {2, 3}          |
| 4        | container4     | {4}             |
| 5        | subsub         | {2 ,3 ,5}       |
```

and I'd like to transform this in the following:

```
| id       | name           | path                             |
|--------  |--------------  |----------------------------------|
| 1        | container1     | /container1                      |
| 2        | container2     | /container2                      |
| 3        | subcontainer1  | /container2/subcontainer1        |
| 4        | container4     | /container4                      |
| 5        | subsub         | /container2/subcontainer1/subsub |
```

I'd like as much as possible to give this to the database to execute, but unfortunately I lack the sql skills. If it's not possible I'll try to get this done inside the app.

Can this be achieved in SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for recursion. We can unnest the array in a lateral join, bring the corresponding names with a join, then aggregate back:

```
select t.*, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(t1.name, '/' order by x.ord) path
    from unnest(t. traversal_ids) with ordinality x(id, ord)
    inner join mytable t1 on t1.id = x.id
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `traversal ids` are always with ascendant order, You can do it using a simple `inner join` with `ANY` operator as follows :

```
with cte as (
  select t2.id, t2.name, t1.name as sub_name, t1.id as sub_id
  from mytable t1
  inner join mytable t2 on t1.id = ANY(t2.traversal_ids)
)
select id, name, '/' || string_agg(sub_name, '/' order by sub_id) as path
from cte
group by id, name
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NPmw1tOj)

Comment: Yes, but this orders the array elements by id, while one would expect them to respect their order in the original array.

Comment: Correct, this is a working solution if the traversal_ids is always ascendant, thanks for the remark